# toggle table rows created dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, jquery

I am dynamically adding rows to table. each row will either be a parent row or child row. I want to toggle visibility of child rows when clicked on its parent row.

```
if (response != null && response != "")
                            {
                                $(response).each(
                                        function()
                                        {
                                            if (this.name == "Opening Balance") // opening balance
                                            {
                                                $('#receipt_table').append(
                                                        '<tr class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse"><th><b>' + this.name
                                                                + '</b></td><th></th><th style="text-align:right"><b>' + this.amount
                                                                + '</b></th></tr>');
                                                receipt_total = this.amount;
                                            }
                                            else if (this.flagGSL == "O"  && this.flagPC=="P")
                                            {
                                                $('#receipt_table').append(
                                                        '<tr id="'+this.name+'" class="header" bgcolor = #ffff10><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;' + this.name + '</td><td style="text-align:right">'
                                                                + this.amount + '</td><td></td></tr>');
                                                var myEl = document.getElementById(this.name);

                                             myEl.addEventListener('click', function() {
                                                 alert('Clicked');
                                             }, false);

                                            }
                                            else if (this.flagGSL == "O"  && this.flagPC=="C")
                                                {  
                                                 $('#receipt_table').append(
                                                            '<tr class="child"><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;' + this.name + '</td><td style="text-align:right">'
                                                                    + this.amount + '</td><td></td></tr>');
                                                }
                                        });
                            }
```

In above code the parent row will have the same id as its name. its child will have class as "child". please suggest me a solution using which i can toggle child rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to separate the dynamic content and the event handler

```
if (response != null && response != "") {
    $(response).each(function () {
        if (this.name == "Opening Balance") // opening balance
        {
            $('#receipt_table').append(
                '<tr class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse"><th><b>' + this.name + '</b></td><th></th><th style="text-align:right"><b>' + this.amount + '</b></th></tr>');
            receipt_total = this.amount;
        } else if (this.flagGSL == "O" && this.flagPC == "P") {
            $('#receipt_table').append(
                '<tr id="' + this.name + '" class="header" bgcolor = #ffff10><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;' + this.name + '</td><td style="text-align:right">' + this.amount + '</td><td></td></tr>');
        } else if (this.flagGSL == "O" && this.flagPC == "C") {
            $('#receipt_table').append(
                '<tr class="child"><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;' + this.name + '</td><td style="text-align:right">' + this.amount + '</td><td></td></tr>');
        }
    });
}
```

then on dom ready handler

```
jQuery(function () {
    $('#receipt_table').on('click', '.header', function () {
        $(this).nextUntil('.header', '.child').toggle()
    })
})
```

Comment: Also, it would be nice to remove the markup from the code altogether, and use a templating library, like http://handlebarsjs.com/